# Can we minimize two variable function by minimizing w.r.t one variable first followed by the other?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following problem.

> Given a rectangular paper of size $2y+8$ and $16-y$. A quadrilateral $PQRS$ in green color below is obtained by removing the four triangles. What is the smallest area of this quadrilateral?
> [image]

## Question

Can we minimize the paper area $(2y+8)(16-y)$ first in which I get $y=6$ and plug it to minimize the required area $(10)(20)-x(20-2x)-2x(10-x)$ in which I get $x=5$?

The required area can be represented as follows

\begin{align}
\text{required area} &= 128 + 24 y - 2 y^2 + 4 (-10 + x) x
\end{align}

No $xy$ terms involved.

Comment: $y$ is given. Maximize the area of triangles in terms of $y$. That will minimize the area of the quadrilateral.

Comment: In general: you can't, but it might work for some (probably quite simple) systems. It could be considered a 'greedy' approach. If you keep iterating from one variable to the other minimizing in turn until convergence, this will work for a wider range of systems than the first, but won't always work absolutely for every system in general.

Comment: Maximum will be when $x = 0$ which is the rectangle itself. So smallest quadrilateral area makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before solving any optimization problem, the very **first** thing to do is to make **two things** clear, if that's not already the case:

1. **The objective function.**
2. **The constraints.**

For 1, simple calculation gives
\begin{align}A &= \text{(area of quadrilateral)} \\
&= \text{(area of rectangle)} - \text{(area of triangles)}\\
&= (2y + 8)(16-y) - [2x (16 - y - x) + x (2y + 8 - 2x)]\\
&= 2(-y^2 + 12y + 64) + 4(x^2 - 10x).
\end{align}

We need to minimize this function with respect to the following constraints:
\begin{equation}
0 \le 2y + 8,\quad 0 \le 16 - y,\quad 0 \le x \le 16 - y,\quad 0 \le 2x \le 2y + 8,
\end{equation}
which can be simplified as
\begin{equation}
x \ge 0,\quad x-4 \le y \le 16-x.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we have reduced the problem to

> Can we minimize two variable function by minimizing w.r.t one variable
> first followed by the other?

The answer is Yes, but you need to do it correctly.

Suppose we have for example the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\min f(x,y) \quad \mbox{s.t. } g(x,y) \ge 0
\end{equation}
You can minimize over $x$ first by fixing $y$ and solving
$$\min_{x: g(x,y) \ge 0} f(x,y).$$
Suppose that you can solve this analytically to obtain the optimal $x^* = h(y)$, then you can plug this into the original objective and minimize over $y$:
$$\min_{y: g(h(y),y) \ge 0} f(h(y),y).$$

Now back to the original problem. We need to minimize $f(x) + g(y)$ subject to $x \ge 0,x-4 \le y \le 16-x$, where $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are quadratic functions.

You can start by fixing $x$ and minimizing over $y$. This is just minimizing a quadratic function over an interval, so you can totally do that. Once you have found the solution (which is a function on $x$), plug it to the original problem and reduce it to, again, minimizing a quadratic function (of $x$) over an interval.

Hint: At some point you may want to use a change of variables for a nicer solution: $a = x - 5, b=y-6$ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Area of triangles $A_T = 2x (16 - y - x) + x (2y + 8 - 2x)$

$A_T = 32x - 2xy - 2x^2 + 2xy + 8x - 2x^2$

$A_T = 40x - 4x^2$

So you can see it is not dependent on $y$. Now if you maximize the area of the triangles, you get

$x = 5, A_T = 100$. Of course this will work only for a range of $y, 1 \lt y \lt 11$

So subtract from rectangle area and you get smallest quadrilateral area in terms of $y$.

Comment: But $x = 5$ not possible for all values.

Comment: Because $x$ is on $16-y$ side of the rectangle and $2x$ on the $2y + 8$ side. otherwise you are right, $-4\lt y \lt 16$